# Componental independence of 2d-vector with split support.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, independence

Let $Z:=(X,Y)$ be an absolutely continuous $\mathbb{R}^2$-valued random variable with density $\zeta\in C(\mathbb{R}^2)$.

Suppose that the support $C:=\mathrm{supp}\,\zeta \stackrel{\mathrm{def}}{=}\overline{\{\zeta>0\}}^{|\cdot|_2}$ can be partitioned into two connected components on each of which the density $\zeta$ factorizes, i.e. suppose that

$$C=C_1\sqcup C_2, \ \ C_1, C_2 \text{ connected,}\quad \text{such that}\quad \left.\zeta\right|_{C_i}\!\equiv \left.\zeta\right|_{C_i}\!(x,y) = \alpha_i(x)\cdot\beta_i(y) \quad(i=1,2)$$
for some functions $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \beta_1, \beta_2 : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.

Can we infer that the components $X$ and $Y$ (of $Z$) are independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They cannot be independent except in very special cases. If they are independent then $\zeta (x,y)$ has the form $f(x)g(y)$. In $C_1$ we get $f(x)g(y)=\alpha_1(x)\beta_1(y)$ which forces $f(x)$ to be multiple of $\alpha_1(x)$ a.e. on then whole real line. Similarly, $f(x)$ is constant times $\alpha_2(x)$ on the whole line.  This forces $\alpha_1$ to be a multiple of $\alpha_2$. Similarly, $\beta_1$ has to be a multiple of $\beta_2$.